# GeckoDriver not ignoring web page's JS error while initiating connection with Firefox browser even in Chrome, Edge it's working fine

Tags: firefox, geckodriver

when I run my test in FIrefox using GeckoDriver then due to some JS errors. It's not initiating connection with browser. How to ignore JS error in geckodriver ? In chrome & Edge same test is running successfully.

below is console's log

1623152204003   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:23230
1623152204644   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\Users\MOHADANI\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofilegdGpTN"
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
1623152206874   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54961
1623152207308   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Jun 08, 2021 5:06:47 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript error: https://10.40.80.211:7395/FCJNeoWeb/LoginServlet, line 109: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Answer (score 0):

By the information given it is hard to say what's wrong with the test. None of the above mentioned JS errors should actually cause issues for geckodriver to connect to Firefox. And as I can see Marionette, which is the internal remote protocol handling the WebDriver commands, is running and listening on port 54961.

To actually being able to give a qualified answer I would have to take a look at the [trace logs as produced by geckodriver](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/TraceLogs.html). Those will tell why geckodriver isn't able to connect. Probably it tries to establish a connection via a different port as the one above.